# Update node folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies

I have a node modules folder called "mynode" which have several functions that I need to use for my node project.

in the package.json , I have it as dependencies such as

```
   "dependencies": {
       "mynode": "file:mynode"
    }
```

Now I add more functions into mynode folder, I seem can't use the new functions which I just add. It keep give me the error such as

```
     TypeError: myfunction.funcA is not a function
```

I dont know how can I make funcA available so that it can run in the project? 
I tried to run

```
   npm install
```

to update the package.json but I still have the TypeError ... is no a function

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, You should module.exports your functions in a .js file, and then You should require it in the file, that you need it for.

there is no need to modify package.json.

Check this out:

https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Comment: The file used to work fine until I add more function into that. I think that I need some kind of update so that the project can see my new function. I dont know how to update it :(